# Count elements in nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a nested list, like

```
lst = [(123, 'bbb', 'bcd'), (245, 'brb', 'gsh'), (832, 'sge', 'hsw'), 
       (832, 'sge', 'aww'), (123, 'sge', 'hsw'), (123, 'sse', 'hsw')]
```

I need to count how many times in this list there are the same 1st item inside nested lists. The output should be like

```
123 - 3 times, 832 - 2 times, 245 - 1 time.
```

I read about collections module, but can't understand how to implement it and if it is useful here.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Create a dictionary called elements. Loop over the list and increment counts of each element and map it in the dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a `Counter` on the list of first items of the tuples:

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [(123, 'bbb', 'bcd'), (245, 'brb', 'gsh'), (832, 'sge', 'hsw'), 
       (832, 'sge', 'aww'), (123, 'sge', 'hsw'), (123, 'sse', 'hsw')]

Counter((tup[0] for tup in lst))
# Counter({123: 3, 245: 1, 832: 2})
```

(I used a generator expression instead of a list, so no intermediate list gets built.)